# Is there a way to use functions from unistd.h in Rust code?

Tags: rust, ffi, sbrk

I'm trying to implement a malloc type function, but I can't figure out what to use instead of the sbrk function found in unistd.h for C. Is there any way to FFI unistd.h into a Rust program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) book as some good info on FFI. If you use [`libc`](https://crates.io/crates/libc), and [cargo](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html) you could use something like the following.

```
extern crate libc;

use libc;

extern {
    fn sbrk(x: usize) -> *mut libc::c_void;
}

fn call_sbrk(x: usize) -> *mut libc::c_void {
    unsafe {
        sbrk(x)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = call_sbrk(42);
    println!("{:p}", x);
}
```

with something like the following in your `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
libc = "^0.2.7"
```

Comment: Nota bene: [one should shy away from using `pkg = "*"`](http://doc.crates.io/faq.html#can-libraries-use--as-a-version-for-their-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for catching my laziness! The post has been edited.

Comment: Cheers, that's perfect - I was close but thought I needed some `#[link(name = "")]` thing in there, and couldn't figure out what to put as the name.

Comment: If you're writing an allocator, you may also be interested in this chapter on Rust [Custom Allocators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/custom-allocators.html)

Comment: @DanielRobertson That looks like an interesting chapter, I'll have to give it a god once I've sorted my allocator out. I'm now having some trouble with global variables and FFI - I've followed the chapter on it, but the linker is saying they're undefined but the names have had an underscore put before them. e.g. `PROT_WRITE` is showing as `_PROT_WRITE`. Any ideas?

Comment: Just realised they aren't global variables, they're macro defined constants, which FFI can't handle.